# CodePipeline with Terraform and Beanstalk

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, terraform, aws-codepipeline, terraform-provider-aws

I'm trying to create a pipeline to deploy on Beanstalk but I constantly get an error in the `deploy` section of the pipeline:

```
Insufficient permissions
The provided role does not have sufficient permissions to access 
Elastic Beanstalk: Access Denied
```

What am I missing?

```
/************************************************
 * Code Build
 ***********************************************/

resource "aws_codebuild_project" "project-name-codebuild" {
  name = "${var.project}-codebuild"
  build_timeout = "15"
  service_role = "${aws_iam_role.project-name-codebuild-role.arn}"

  artifacts {
    type = "CODEPIPELINE"
  }

  environment {
    compute_type = "BUILD_GENERAL1_SMALL"
    type = "LINUX_CONTAINER"
    image = "aws/codebuild/java:openjdk-8"
  }

  source {
    type = "CODEPIPELINE"
  }

  tags {
    Name = "${var.project}"
    Environment = "${var.environment}"
  }
}

resource "aws_ecr_repository" "project-name-ecr-repository" {
  name = "${var.project}-ecr-repository"
}

resource "aws_iam_role" "project-name-codebuild-role" {
  name = "${var.project}-codebuild-role"

  assume_role_policy = <<EOF
{
      "Version": "2012-10-17",
      "Statement": [
        {
          "Effect": "Allow",
          "Principal": {
            "Service": "codebuild.amazonaws.com"
          },
          "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
        }
      ]
    }
EOF
}

resource "aws_iam_role_policy" "project-name-codebuild-role-policy" {
  role = "${aws_iam_role.project-name-codebuild-role.id}"

  policy = <<POLICY
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Resource": [
        "*"
      ],
      "Action": [
        "logs:CreateLogGroup",
        "logs:CreateLogStream",
        "logs:PutLogEvents"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
POLICY
}

resource "aws_iam_role_policy_attachment" "project-name-codebuild-role-policy-bucket" {
  policy_arn = "${aws_iam_policy.project-name-code-pipeline-bucket-access.arn}"
  role = "${aws_iam_role.project-name-codebuild-role.name}"
}

/************************************************
 * Code Pipeline
 ***********************************************/

resource "aws_codepipeline" "project-name-code-pipeline" {
  name = "${var.project}-code-pipeline"
  role_arn = "${aws_iam_role.project-name-code-pipeline-role.arn}"

  artifact_store {
    location = "${aws_s3_bucket.project-name-code-pipeline-bucket.bucket}"
    type = "S3"
  }

  stage {
    name = "Source"

    action {
      name = "Source"
      category = "Source"
      owner = "ThirdParty"
      provider = "GitHub"
      version = "1"
      output_artifacts = [
        "source"]

      configuration {
        Owner = "Owner"
        Repo = "project-name"
        Branch = "master"
        OAuthToken = "${var.github-token}"
      }
    }
  }

  stage {
    name = "Build-Everything"

    action {
      name = "Build"
      category = "Build"
      owner = "AWS"
      provider = "CodeBuild"
      input_artifacts = [
        "source"]
      output_artifacts = [
        "build"]
      version = "1"

      configuration {
        ProjectName = "${aws_codebuild_project.project-name-codebuild.name}"
      }
    }
  }

  stage {
    name = "Deploy"

    action {
      name = "Deploy"
      category = "Deploy"
      owner = "AWS"
      provider = "ElasticBeanstalk"
      input_artifacts = [
        "build"]
      version = "1"

      configuration {
        ApplicationName = "${aws_elastic_beanstalk_application.project-name.name}"
        EnvironmentName = "${aws_elastic_beanstalk_environment.project-name-environment.name}"
      }
    }
  }
}

resource "aws_s3_bucket" "project-name-code-pipeline-bucket" {
  bucket = "${var.project}-code-pipeline-bucket"
  acl = "private"
}

resource "aws_iam_policy" "project-name-code-pipeline-bucket-access" {
  name = "${var.project}-code-pipeline-bucket-access"

  policy = <<POLICY
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
      {
        "Effect":"Allow",
        "Resource": [
          "${aws_s3_bucket.project-name-code-pipeline-bucket.arn}",
          "${aws_s3_bucket.project-name-code-pipeline-bucket.arn}/*"
        ],
        "Action": [
          "s3:CreateBucket",
          "s3:GetAccelerateConfiguration",
          "s3:GetBucketAcl",
          "s3:GetBucketCORS",
          "s3:GetBucketLocation",
          "s3:GetBucketLogging",
          "s3:GetBucketNotification",
          "s3:GetBucketPolicy",
          "s3:GetBucketRequestPayment",
          "s3:GetBucketTagging",
          "s3:GetBucketVersioning",
          "s3:GetBucketWebsite",
          "s3:GetLifecycleConfiguration",
          "s3:GetObject",
          "s3:GetObjectAcl",
          "s3:GetObjectTagging",
          "s3:GetObjectTorrent",
          "s3:GetObjectVersion",
          "s3:GetObjectVersionAcl",
          "s3:GetObjectVersionTagging",
          "s3:GetObjectVersionTorrent",
          "s3:GetReplicationConfiguration",
          "s3:ListAllMyBuckets",
          "s3:ListBucket",
          "s3:ListBucketMultipartUploads",
          "s3:ListBucketVersions",
          "s3:ListMultipartUploadParts",
          "s3:PutObject"
        ]
      }
  ]
}
POLICY
}

resource "aws_iam_role" "project-name-code-pipeline-role" {
  name = "${var.project}-code-pipeline-role"

  assume_role_policy = <<EOF
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "Service": "codepipeline.amazonaws.com"
      },
      "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
    }
  ]
}
EOF
}

resource "aws_iam_role_policy" "project-name-code-pipeline-role-policy" {
  name = "${var.project}-code-pipeline-role-policy"
  role = "${aws_iam_role.project-name-code-pipeline-role.id}"

  policy = <<EOF
{
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Action": [
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:GetObjectVersion",
                "s3:GetBucketVersioning"
            ],
            "Resource": "*",
            "Effect": "Allow"
        },
        {
            "Action": [
                "s3:PutObject"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::codepipeline*",
                "arn:aws:s3:::elasticbeanstalk*"
            ],
            "Effect": "Allow"
        },
        {
            "Action": [
                "codedeploy:CreateDeployment",
                "codedeploy:GetApplicationRevision",
                "codedeploy:GetDeployment",
                "codedeploy:GetDeploymentConfig",
                "codedeploy:RegisterApplicationRevision"
            ],
            "Resource": "*",
            "Effect": "Allow"
        },
        {
            "Action": [
                "elasticbeanstalk:CreateApplicationVersion",
                "elasticbeanstalk:DescribeApplicationVersions",
                "elasticbeanstalk:DescribeEnvironments",
                "elasticbeanstalk:DescribeEvents",
                "elasticbeanstalk:UpdateEnvironment",
                "autoscaling:DescribeAutoScalingGroups",
                "autoscaling:DescribeLaunchConfigurations",
                "autoscaling:DescribeScalingActivities",
                "autoscaling:ResumeProcesses",
                "autoscaling:SuspendProcesses",
                "cloudformation:GetTemplate",
                "cloudformation:DescribeStackResource",
                "cloudformation:DescribeStackResources",
                "cloudformation:DescribeStackEvents",
                "cloudformation:DescribeStacks",
                "cloudformation:UpdateStack",
                "ec2:DescribeInstances",
                "ec2:DescribeImages",
                "ec2:DescribeAddresses",
                "ec2:DescribeSubnets",
                "ec2:DescribeVpcs",
                "ec2:DescribeSecurityGroups",
                "ec2:DescribeKeyPairs",
                "elasticloadbalancing:DescribeLoadBalancers",
                "rds:DescribeDBInstances",
                "rds:DescribeOrderableDBInstanceOptions",
                "sns:ListSubscriptionsByTopic"
            ],
            "Resource": "*",
            "Effect": "Allow"
        },
        {
            "Action": [
                "lambda:invokefunction",
                "lambda:listfunctions"
            ],
            "Resource": "*",
            "Effect": "Allow"
        },
        {
            "Action": [
                "s3:ListBucket",
                "s3:GetBucketPolicy",
                "s3:GetObjectAcl",
                "s3:PutObjectAcl",
                "s3:DeleteObject"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::elasticbeanstalk*",
            "Effect": "Allow"
        }
    ],
    "Version": "2012-10-17"
}
EOF
}

resource "aws_iam_role_policy_attachment" "project-name-code-pipeline-role-policy-attachment" {
  policy_arn = "${aws_iam_policy.project-name-code-pipeline-bucket-access.arn}"
  role = "${aws_iam_role.project-name-code-pipeline-role.name}"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Came across the same problem,
the issue is that you need to enable s3 access to "arn:aws:s3:::elasticbeanstalk*"

Agree that error message is kind of obscure

Comment: is there way to drill deeper into this error now adays?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest checking these things to debug:

1. Did the template create the resources you were expecting?

   1. Does the pipeline role have the right policy attached to it? You can run `aws codepipeline get-pipeline` to get the pipeline's ARN, and use the IAM console to check that the policy is what you expect.
2. Are you missing some elastic beanstalk permissions in the policy? I'm not sure you are, but try to change the policy to `"elasticbeanstalk:*"`.
3. Try to assume the pipeline's role in the console, and try to deploy the elastic beanstalk instance, see if you get any more detailed information from the elastic beanstalk console.

Answer (score 0):

The ARN arn:aws:s3:::elasticbeanstalk* in the provided policy statement is incorrect.
The correct ARN format for an S3 bucket follows the pattern arn:aws:s3:::bucket-name. In the given policy statement, the ARN should be specific to the bucket name or a specific bucket. Using a wildcard (*) in the ARN is not valid for S3 bucket resources.